# Including constants without functions

Tags: c++, constants, ambiguous

I am making a c++ library and I want to include fcntl.h in the header (for the permission constants)

But I have a function called open, the argument list contains classes that can be casted to the fcntl's open argument list types.

That means when i use `#include<fcntl.h>` I am getting an ambiguous error.

I want the library to be as portable as possible.

I thought of changing the name from open to Open but is there a better solution?

Like including the header without parsing the functions(eg. Just including the constants).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there a better solution?

Use a namespace:

```
namespace my_lib {
  int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
}
```

And to be clear, a library should always declare its functions/classes/constants/etc... in a namespace, not just as a means to fix a specific issue. This way, you avoid potential conflicts with other libraries that users might be including that you have no visibility on.

**Edit:** From the followup in the comment, if prefixing things with a namespace gets annoying, you can locally use individual identifiers from a namespace, and that will not be ambiguous, nor will is cause conflicts elsewhere in the code.

```
#include <fcntl.h>

namespace my_lib {
    int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
}

void foo() {
    using my_lib::open;
    
    open("aaa", 0);
}
```

You should **never** resort to `using namespace my_lib`. However, should you be painted in a corner (e.g. the `using namespace` is in code you can't change), you can resolve conflicts by explicitly referring to the namespace for the ambiguous symbol.

```
#include <fcntl.h>

namespace my_lib {
    void bar();
    int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
}

using namespace my_lib;

void foo() {
    bar();

    // use the open() from fcntl.h
    ::open("aaa", 0);

    // Use the open() from my_lib
    ::my_lib::open("aaa", 0);
}
```

Comment: I am, the issue comes when I use using namespace xxx; in a program. I want to be able to do that too. That's because I wanna upgrade it to a framework in the future

Comment: @VBrawl This is precisely why so many people keep saying that `using namespace xxx;` should never be used. Stop using it and your problem goes away.

Comment: Yeah, but i am planning to make a framework using this library, so it's hard to keep using XXX::open or any other function

Comment: @Vbrawl In that case, you can use local namespace usage, like this: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8TEK9a8cv

Comment: The edit is useful, would it be possible to include fcntl in a custom namespace instead? If not I'll just use your solution

Comment: @Vbrawl No. The namespace changes the mangled name of symbols. You can't just wrap a library around a namespace. You'd have to add a whole shim library around it as well.